# Change CSS style of timescale buttons in Plotly Timeseries Chart

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, plotly-dash

I am pretty new to Dash/Plotly and I am trying to style the timescale buttons with CSS but it seems that none of the classes is reacting to the styles I apply. I have something similar to this:

[Plotly Time Series Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLo32.png)

https://plotly.com/python/time-series/

and my goal is to make the buttons bigger and a bit darker with rounded corners. Normally I would do something like that:

```
    button  {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #80848d;
}
```

but in this case it seems that buttons have a  tag and a selector-rect class that are pre-styled.
Has anyone managed to solve the problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can override your styles by using the same class that pre-styled and add `!important` for your styles like that:

```
.class-pre-styled
{
  margin-left: 15px!important;
  margin-right: 15px!important;
}
```

I hope that helps you!